# Getting specific index of a tile in photo gallery with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to get the index of a child element in a homegrown photo gallery slider. I seem to get getting an index of 0, but would like to actually get the number of the slide. I've tried a lot of things and this is the closest I've gotten (tons of tries with just a "-1" as the result). Any tips would be appreciated.

HTML (from an Elixir/Phoenix template)

```html
<div id={"#{@section_id}"} phx-hook="GallerySlider" class="min-w-0">
  <div class="wrapper relative w-full">
    <i id={"left-#{@section_id}"} class="fa-solid fa-angle-left" phx-update="ignore"></i>
    <div class="carousel flex flex-row">
      <%= render_slot(@images) %>
    </div>
    <i id={"right-#{@section_id}"} class="fa-solid fa-angle-right" phx-update="ignore"></i>
  </div>
  <ul id={"dots-#{@section_id}"} class="list-inline dots"></ul>
</div>
```

JS/TS:

```js
const carousel = this.el?.querySelector<HTMLElement>(".carousel")!;
const carouselChildren = carousel.children;

// Function to get the index of a child element within its parent
function getChildIndex(
  parent: string | any[] | HTMLCollection,
  child: Element,
) {
  for (let i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
    if (parent[i] === child) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1; // Child not found
}

// Get the index of a specific child element within the carousel
const targetChild = carouselChildren[0]; // Assuming you want to find the index of the first child element
const index = getChildIndex(carouselChildren, targetChild);

console.log("Index of target child within carousel:", index);
```

This is the console message:

```bash
Index of target child within carousel: 0
```

Comment: Do you ever get anything other than 0 or -1? I'm wondering if the issue is just 0-based indexing, in which case you would just need to return `i+1`

Comment: Can you also add an expected result vs actual result to understand better what you are trying to achieve? From what I understand above, it seems that it returns what you need, i.e. the index of the target child which is 0. Did you try with other indexes? Like carouselChildren[3] for example?

Comment: @DialloFrancisPatrick I did try that, maybe I have answered my own question :D

Comment: @AaronMeese ya when I change the position of the array, it corresponds. Let me try the i+1. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the issue was expecting 1-based indexing while using a 0-based language. Changing your code to the following should give the expected output of the current slide number:

```js
// Function to get the index of a child element within its parent
function getChildIndex(
  parent: string | any[] | HTMLCollection,
  child: Element,
) {
  for (let i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
    if (parent[i] === child) {
      // Return the slide number here, not the actual index
      return i + 1;
    }
  }
  return -1; // Child not found
}
```

IMO it would make sense to change the function name to something more accurate in this case, i.e. `getSlideNumber`, but whatever works in your purview.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `.querySelectorAll` selecting the parent of whatever elements you wish to count provides your array-like object.